# Return the inserted timestamp after inserting a record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I feel like this should be an easy problem.  All I want to do is return the timestamp of the entry that was just inserted, but in the same call.  All I can find in my searching is about returning the identity column(id).  But I just need the timestamp.
Here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertLabelHistory]
    @itemID         VARCHAR(50)
    ,@enterType     INT
    ,@authID        INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO LABEL_CHECK_HIST
    (ITEM_ID, ENTERED_DATE, ENTER_TYPE, AUTH_ID)
    VALUES
    (@itemID, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,@enterType, @authID)
END
```

This is in SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [OUTPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) clause, eg

```
INSERT INTO LABEL_CHECK_HIST (ITEM_ID, ENTERED_DATE, ENTER_TYPE, AUTH_ID)
OUTPUT inserted.ENTERED_DATE
VALUES (@itemID, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,@enterType, @authID)
```